# React native, video player crash without any error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo-av

I'm using `expo-av` for playing Video in my app. It's working fine in every screen. But 2-3 screens it's crashing when I hit play button and it's not giving any error.

below is my code

```
import {Video as VideoPlayer} from "expo-av";

....

const videoRef = useRef(null)

....

 <VideoPlayer
        ref={videoRef}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 120,
          marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(15),
        }}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://superstudent-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/video_original_1624939508019.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        // onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
```

that's the code and I used same code for every screen but it's crashing for 2-3 screens. Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you using the player inside FlatList? I was reading about situation where FlatList was causing some issues. Also, once I had the same issue (not using FlatList) and solved that by setting `opacity: 0.99`. I know, it's crazy, but it was working for me.

Comment: where should I set opacity and It's crashing inside flatlist and also outside flatlist

Comment: I just checked my old code and I actually had problems with the package called `react-native-youtube-iframe`, so I guess that opacity trick will not work for `expo-av`. But anyways, I was setting opacity via `webViewStyle={{opacity: 0.99}}` prop on `<YoutubePlayer/>`.

When you have these kind of issues, where you're sure that you're following packages' docs and it's not working properly, create a new project and do minimal setup with the packages. If you still have the same issue, it means that package itself contains some kind of a bug and it's not how you use that package.

Answer (score 0):

There is an dependency you have to Add the following at the beginning of ./android/app/build.gradle on Android (required for react-native-vector-icons to work): it's work for me